# Insert multiple sql files

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I've 297 sql files, I want import them to mysql but it must be in different databases.

I tried:

```
 find . -name '*.sql' | awk '{ print "source",$0 }' | mysql -u <db_user> -p --batch -D <database_name>
```

but it throws error because sql files has commands like:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXIST <table_name>
```

so I need a script which must create new database per sql file.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I did it with a python script which I wrote.

```
import os

for filename in os.listdir('<path_to_folder_contains_sqls>'):
    print 'importing db: ' + filename
    dbname = 'db_' + str(os.path.splitext(filename)[0])
    os.system('mysql -e "create database ' + dbname + '; use ' + dbname + '; source ' + filename + ';"')
```